# Delete from sublists

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to remove a number (if exists) from sublists, using Higher Order Functions.

```
removeAux :: Int -> [[Int]] -> (Int -> [Int] -> Bool) -> [[Int]]
removeAux num (l:ls) f 
  | f num l = delete num l  -- ERROR in this line
  |otherwise = removeAux num ls f

removeFromSublists :: Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
removeFromSublists _ [[]] = [[]]
removeFromSublists num ls = removeAux num ls (elem)
```

And it's suppose to work like this:

```
> l = [[0,1,2],[2,3]]

> removeFromSublists 1 l
[[0,2],[2,3]]

> removeFromSublists 0 l  $ removeFromSubLists 1 l
[[2],[2,3]]

> removeFromSublists 2 l
[[0,1],[3]]
```

But I have two problems that I don't know how to solve. First it will not delete all the occurrences of the number and it should? And I can't understand why the code doesn't work?
I keep geting the error:

[image]

Can someone help me please?

Comment: the easiest way to do this, in my opinion, is to just combine the basic `map` and `filter` functions for lists

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry but i can't see how?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could help to take a type-driven approach here. As in, you want to remove all occurrences of some element from a list of list of elements.

This is, "given an `a` and a list of list of `a's` (`[[a]]`) return a list of list of `a`'s (`[[a]]`):

```hs
removeAll :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeAll v (list:listOfLists) = ???
```

We're removing all `v` from each `list` in the list `(list:listOfLists)`. Another way of saying this is *"for each `list` in our `listOfLists` filter out `v`"*.

So, we want to perform the same action (filter) for-each value in a list. In Haskell, this translates to *mapping the filter action* over every `list` in the `listOfLists`.

```hs
removeAll :: Eq a => a -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
removeAll v xs = map (filter (/= v)) xs
```